# What's the difference between "cluster" option in linear regression and mixed models?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, clustered-standard-errors

Is there a difference in estimates from linear regression with "cluster" option and linear mixed model?

Take for example [this scenario](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/we...-4-beyond-ols/) :

"...dataset contains data on 400 schools that come from 37 school districts. It is very possible that the scores within each school district may not be independent, and this could lead to residuals that are not independent within districts. *We can use the cluster option to indicate that the observations are clustered into districts*..."

What is the difference between regression with cluster option and a linear mixed model with random intercept/slope for the school district variable?

Comment: Van you give som reference to what is 'cluster' option? Is that an option in som software? Which?

Comment: There are too many examples of "cluster" option (https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/faq/what-are-the-some-of-the-methods-for-analyzing-clustered-data-in-stata/) I guess my question is really what the difference is between them and when/why to chose which. I'm sure these are equivalently available in R [eg lm(), plm()]  and other software